# Can't install Android Studio (IDE cannot create directory Mac)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

I can't install Android Studio on my Mac but a pop up window keeps showing up with an error I have IntelliJ already installed and I don't know if that has anything to do with the issue. I really hope you guys can help me out.

[image]

Comment: Yeah... so... navigate to the level just above directory where you're trying to install Android Studio and select Get Info from the File menu (or command-i). Check the permissions at the bottom of the info window to see if you have permissions on that directory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had problem after installing mac os BigSur,
the problem is because owner of google folder inside Application Support is root

the solution that solve my problem is to change the owner of google folder from root to my current user, you can do **with open terminal / Iterm** and enter command below

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support
sudo chown your_current_user_name ./Google
```

Comment: I can't believe Google allows this bug in such a popular configuration (macOS latest version)...

Answer (score 3):

This problem puzzled me for a long time also. I went to /Users/myname/Library/Application\ Support/Google/ and create AndroidStudio4.1 folder by myself. I solved this problem in this way ,but I think it is a bug of Android Studio.